# Nodejs APi doesn't get result

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm a beginner in Nodejs.
I'm trying to use async/ await to create an api:

```
getAllTasks: function (callback) {
    return db.query("Select * from tasks", callback);
},

function asyncGetAllTask(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        resolve (Task.getAllTasks());
    })
}

router.get('/:id?',  async function (req, res) {
    if(req.params.id){
        await asyncGetTaskByID(req)

        .catch(err=>{
            res.send(400, {status:400, message: 'bad request', type:'client errors'});
        })
        .then(rows=>{
            res.json(rows)
        })
    }
    else {
        await asyncGetAllTask()
        .catch(err=>{
            res.json(err);
        })
        .then(rows=>{
            res.json(rows);
        })
    }
});
```

I'm trying to get all "tasks" from the database (i'm using mysql). However, i don't get the tasks rows. Instead, i get this when i use a get method from postman:

```
{
    "domain": null,
    "_events": {},
    "_eventsCount": 0,
    "_callSite": {},
    "_ended": false,
    "_idleNext": null,
    "_idlePrev": null,
    "_idleStart": null,
    "_idleTimeout": -1,
    "_repeat": null,
    "sql": "Select * from tasks",
    "typeCast": true,
    "nestTables": false,
    "_resultSet": null,
    "_results": [],
    "_fields": [],
    "_index": 0,
    "_loadError": null
}
```

Am i missing some thing? I don't understand somehow i got the wrong result. 
Sorry for my English.
Thank you

Comment: You have `getAllTasks()` that expects a callback to be passed to it, but then you don't pass the callback when you call `Task.getAllTasks()`.   That will not work.  Wrapping it in a promise does not help at all.  And, you can ONLY use `await` on promises so the thing you're awaiting has to be a promise or it won't await anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of the `await` keyword, with the promise interface and handlers (ie `.catch()` and `.then()`) looks in correct here.

If you want to use `await`, you should restructure your code along the lines of this (note the use of `try` and `catch`, to achieve the catch-like behaviour that you want for error handling):

```
router.get('/:id?',  async function (req, res) {

try {
    if(req.params.id){
        // Correct use of await typically does not require the use of .then() 
        // and is as follows
        const rows = await asyncGetTaskByID(req) 
        res.json(rows)
    }
    else {
        // Correct use of await typically does not require the use of .then() 
        // and is as follows
        const rows = await asyncGetAllTask()
        res.json(rows);
    }
}
catch(err) { // Catch block to return error result
    res.send(500, {status:500, message: 'an error occurred'});
}
});
```

Additionally, you will likely need to update your method `asyncGetAllTask()` to the following:

```
function asyncGetAllTask(){

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        // The resolve callback should probably be passed to getAllTasks 
        // as per your defintion of Task.getAllTasks
        Task.getAllTasks((error, rows) => {
            if(error) { 
                reject(error); 
            } else { 
                resolve(rows); 
            }
        }); 
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i still get the same above result, instead of this:
[
    {
        "taskid": 1,
        "taskname": "task a",
        "dateCreated": "2018-07-10T17:00:00.000Z",
        "description": "description a"
    },
    {
        "taskid": 2,
        "taskname": "task b",
        "dateCreated": "2018-07-10T17:00:00.000Z",
        "description": "description b"
    },

Comment: See my update with detail for `asyncGetAllTask()` -  does this help?